# Purely "discrete" PDEs?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, discrete-calculus

Usually, one formulates a system of continuous PDEs and then discretizes it in order to approximately solve it.

Is there a view point that instead formulates a system of "discrete" PDEs, which therefore do not require a discretization step in order to solve it, even if some other type of reformulation may be required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be interested in the area of [Discrete Differential Geometry](http://www.siggraph.org/asia2008/attendees/courses/14.php).

> The behavior of physical systems is typically described by a set of
>   continuous equations using tools such as geometric mechanics and
>   differential geometry to analyze and capture their properties. For
>   purposes of computation, one must derive discrete (in space and time)
>   representations of the underlying equations. Researchers in a variety
>   of areas have discovered that theories, which are discrete from the
>   start and have key geometric properties built into their discrete
>   description, can often more readily yield robust numerical simulations
>   that are true to the underlying continuous systems: they exactly
>   preserve invariants of the continuous systems in the discrete
>   computational realm.

Comment: I felt so giddy and excited reading that webpage. I wish I could have attended that conference. Anyway, I have this book on [discrete and computational geometry](http://www.amazon.ca/Discrete-Computational-Geometry-Satyan-Devadoss/dp/0691145539) (not discrete *differential* geometry) on my bookshelf -- should I start reading that as a pre-requisite? Or is discrete differential geometry pretty separate?

Comment: It looks like really cool stuff!  I haven't studied this material myself, but the course notes found [here](http://ddg.cs.columbia.edu/) look like a good place to dive in.  They might give you an idea of how much prerequisite knowledge from the textbook you mentioned is necessary.

Comment: See also Peter Saveliev's site: [Intelligent Perception](http://inperc.com/wiki/index.php?title=Math._Images._Software.), especially the material on discrete (exterior) calculus. As for *Discrete and Computational Geometry* by Devadoss & O'Rourke, even though I wouldn't call it a specific prerequisite for discrete differential geometry, it is a great introduction to important basic concepts such as polygons, polyhedra, triangulations and convex hulls. It even touches on discrete differential geometry in a section on the Gauss-Bonnet theorem for polyhedra.

Answer (score 3):

You can consider cellular automata. See [Cellular Automata Modeling of Physical Systems](http://cui.unige.ch/~chopard/CA/Book/book.html) (Chopard & Droz, CUP 1998) for the application of cellular automata to modeling physical systems.